# Qt program error

Tags: c++, qt

I made following program just for practice in Qt. My program crashes when I click an item in Listwidget so that the row number of that Item becomes an item in Listwidget_2. Here is the code. MainWindow.h is the same as generated by Qt IDE(no changes has been made, all the functions are predefined which have been used in .cpp file). Please also notify if i am making any memory leaks in the program because I am a beginner.

Thanks for your help!

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextStream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
     ui->setupUi(this);
    noofitems=0;
    files.setFileName("E:/filev.txt");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionDelete_Item_triggered()
{

      qDeleteAll(ui->listWidget->selectedItems());
}

void MainWindow::on_okbutton_clicked()
{
    QListWidgetItem *item=new QListWidgetItem;

    item->setText(ui->lineEdit->text());
    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
    noofitems++;

    writefile();
}

void MainWindow::writefile()
{
    QFile files("E:/legitfile.txt");

    if(files.exists())
    {
        if(!files.open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text))
        {
            QMessageBox::warning(this,"File Access!!!","The File containing data of the         Items and Comments can't be acessed",QMessageBox::Ok);
        }
    }else
        if(!files.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
            QMessageBox::warning(this,"File Access!!!","The File containing data of the     Items and Comments can't be acessed",QMessageBox::Ok);
        }

    QTextStream out(&files);
    out<< noofitems<<',';

    files.flush();
    files.close();
}
```

***THE PROGRAM CRASHES WHEN THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION IS CALLED***

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    QListWidgetItem *itm=new QListWidgetItem;
    itm->setText((char*)(ui->listWidget->currentRow()));
    ui->listWidget_2->addItem(itm);
}
```

Comment: You should add debug output to see at which line it crashes exactly.

Comment: how can i do that in the notified program. I tried it but the program wont compile

Comment: add an include `#include <QtCore/QDebug>` and then do for example `qDebug() << "point 1";`, `qDebug() << "point 2";` around your lines to get debug output. Or use an IDE (like QtCreator) which allows step-by-step-debugging

Comment: the program compiles fine, but when i click the added item in listwidget, then program crashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
     Q_ASSERT( ui );
     Q_ASSERT( ui->listWidget );
     Q_ASSERT( ui->listWidget_2 );

     QListWidgetItem *itm=new QListWidgetItem;
     itm->setText( QString::number( ui->listWidget->currentRow() ) );
     ui->listWidget_2->addItem(itm);
}
```

If any of the assertions fires, that means either `ui`, `ui->listWidget` or `ui->listWidget_2` ist not initialised.
Also note how I changed the line which converts `currentRow()` into a number. This is more readable and I'm not sure if converting the row to (char*) is actually the line which crashes your program

Comment: Thanks alot sir the program was crashing because of type casting char*. What is the reason behind that.
May God bless you. I hate those people whihc just lower down the ranking of beginers so that can't ask questions and get baned.

Comment: If you convert an integer, e.g. 5 to char*, you don't get the readable character "5" but instead whatever is asigned to the ASCII code 5. If you wanted "5" you would have to convert 53 into a char* because the string literal "5" has that ASCII code. Long story short, just use `QString::number()`, `QString::arg()` and `QString.toInt()` for number<->string conversions with Qt and you don't have to care about ASCII and so on.

Comment: You cannot convert ints to char* strings by casting, you need a specific function like atoi or QString::number(). Casting will make any function taking char* interpret the int as 4 characters, and then might continue to read the (potentially invalid) memory after the int (<- crash), until it finds a null byte, as it expects the string to be null-terminated.

Comment: That's actually right. I think what I described would be casting `int` to `char` (as opposed to `char*`)